Proving that the family $\{U_i,\phi_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ is an atlas of the projective space.
We have the binary equivalence relation $$xRy \iff \exists\lambda\in\mathbb{R}:x=\lambda y$$ so the quotient space
$$(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/{R}$$
is the projective space.
Then, we define $V_i=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}:x_i\neq 0\}$, $U_i=\pi(V_i)$, where $\pi$ is the application that maps a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ to its equivalence class $[x]_R$ and
$$\phi_i:U_i\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$ as $$\phi_i([x]_R)=\dfrac{1}{x_i}(x_1,...,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_{n+1})$$
I have to prove that the family $\{U_i,\phi_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ is an atlas for the projective space, i.e, with the definition I am using, I have to prove that

$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} U_i =\mathbb{R}P^n$ and $\phi_i$ is injective $\forall i=1,...,n+1$

For $i\neq j,\quad \phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\quad$ and $\quad \phi_j(U_i\cap U_j) \quad$ are open sets, and $\phi_i\circ\phi_j^{-1}$ is differentiable of class $C^k$.


I have already done the first part but I am having trouble proving that the sets mentioned in 2 are open. I have checked the answer provided and I don't understand the procedure followed: first, we prove that $\phi_i(U_i)=\mathbb{R}^n$ and then we take $[x]_R\in U_i\cap U_j$ and we prove that $$\phi_i([x])=\phi_i([\frac{1}{x_i}x])\in \mathbb{R}^{j-2}\times\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-j}$$
I get the first step but I am not sure why this is not enough to prove that the intersection is an open set. If $\phi_i(U_i)$ is an open set and $\phi_i(U_j)$ is also an open set, does this not mean that $\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)$ is also an open set? Why do we need the last step too?

$\phi_i (U_i)$ is not $\mathbb{RP}^n$. It seems you are misunderstanding something.

Yes, that was a typo. I meant $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$U_i \cap U_j$ is specified by $x_i , x_j\neq 0$. Try to write $\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)$ and $\phi_j(U_i \cap U_j)$ explicitly.

Maybe you think that since $U_i$ and $U_j$ are open sets, so is their intersection. However, we still do not have any topology on the projective space. So one needs to check that those images are open

There are lot of things which have to be checked.
The key is to observe that the quotient map $\pi: \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb RP^n$ is an open map. Note that all open maps are quotient maps, but the converse fails. See for example When is a quotient map open?
To see that $\pi$ is open, let $V \subset \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ be open. Then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(V)) = \{ \lambda x \mid \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}, x \in V \} = \bigcup_{\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}} \lambda V$, where $\lambda V =  \{ \lambda x \mid x \in V \}$. Since multiplication with $\lambda \ne 0$ gives a self-homeomorphism on $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ (its inverse being multiplication with $1/\lambda$), all $\lambda V$ are open and so is their union. We conclude that $\pi(V)$ is open in $\mathbb RP^n$.
Since $V_i$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, the restriction $\pi_i : V_i \to U_i$ of $\pi$ is an open map, hence a quotient map.
We conclude  that $\phi_i$ is continuous (this follows from the obvious continuity of $\phi_i \circ \pi_i : V_i \to \mathbb R^n$).
The map $f_i : \mathbb R^n \to U_i, f_i(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = (y_1,\ldots,y_{i-1},1,y_i,\ldots, y_n)$ is clearly continuous. Thus $\psi_i = \pi_i \circ f_i : \mathbb R^n \to V_i$ is continuous. It is easy to check that $\psi_i \circ \phi_i = id$ and $\phi_i \circ \psi_i = id$, and this shows that $\phi_i$ is a homeomorphism.
Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}U_i =   \mathbb RP^n$, the homeomorphisms $\phi_i$ form an atlas for $ \mathbb RP^n$. As in any atlas, the intersections $U_i \cap U_j$ are open and mapped by $\phi_i,  \phi_j$ homeomorphically to open subsets $\phi_i(U_1 \cap U_j)$,  $\phi_j(U_1 \cap U_j)$ of $\mathbb R^n$.
It remains to show that the transition functions $\phi_{ji} = \phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1} : \phi_j(U_1 \cap U_j) \to  \phi_i(U_1 \cap U_j)$ are smooth (i.e. of class $C^\infty$). This is trivial for $i = j$. Let us consider the case $i < j$ (the case $j < i$ is treated similarly). We have
$$\phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1} = \phi_i \circ \psi_j = \phi_i \circ \pi_j \circ f_j$$
and therefore
$$\phi_{ji}(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = \phi_i([y_1,\ldots,y_{j-1},1,y_j,\ldots, y_n]) \\= (\frac{y_1}{y_i}, \ldots, \frac{y_{i-1}}{y_i}, \frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}, \ldots, \frac{y_{j-1}}{y_i}, \frac{1}{y_i},\frac{y_j}{y_i}, \ldots, \frac{y_n}{y_i}) .$$
All $n$ component functions are clearly smooth, thus $\phi_{ji}$ is smooth.
Although it is irrelevant, let us finally determine $U_i \cap U_j$. Clearly $\pi^{-1}(U_i \cap U_j) = \pi^{-1}(U_i) \cap \pi^{-1}(U_j) = V_i \cap V_j$, thus $U_i \cap U_j =  \pi(V_i \cap V_j)$.
